# Typesafe Swing events—"The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time"

Tags: swing, scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I am implementing a Swing component and I want to overcome the #### untypedness of `Reactor`. So I thought this would work:

```
trait Foo[A] extends scala.swing.Publisher {
  final case class Bar(parent: Vector[A], children: A*) extends scala.swing.event.Event
}

trait Test {
  val foo: Foo[Int]

  foo.reactions += {
    case foo.Bar(parent, children) => {
      println(parent.sum - children)
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately that gives me two compiler warnings:

```
The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time.
  final case class Bar(parent: Vector[A], children: A*) extends scala.swing.event.Event
                   ^
The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time.
    case foo.Bar(parent, children) => {
                ^
```

Should I ignore these warnings? Can I suppress them? Should I change the design?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Scala, inner classes are "path-dependent".

I'll use your code as an example. If you have two `Foo[Int]`s, called `foo` and `bar`, then `foo.Bar` is a different type to `bar.Bar`. Note that this differs from Java's idea of inner classes, where `foo.Bar` and `bar.Bar` are the same type.

In any case, the JVM doesn't support inner classes directly, so in both Java and Scala, the class Bar compiles to a JVM class called `Foo$Bar`. Instances of inner classes *almost* always contain a reference to their owner - the "outer reference".

Now, when you've got a pattern match on a path dependent type (like the one in your code), the Scala compiler will produce bytecode which does two things: it will check the class (so it will check that the object it received is an instance of `Foo$Bar`), and it will check the outer reference (so it will check that the outer reference of the object received is `foo`).

However, in your code, the compiler can't find a way to check the outer reference, because you've declared your inner class as final.

So, if you ignore the warning, then your pattern will match all instances of `Foo$Bar`, even if they don't belong to `foo`. You'll have a better idea than me whether this will be a problem.

Or, you can fix it by making your inner class non-final.

P.s, I'm not entirely sure why the Scala compiler can't check outer references on final inner classes, but I've found that if an inner class is final, then `outer$` is private, whereas if it's non-final, `outer$` is public. It might be worth a poke around in the compiler's internals, to figure out why this is.

### Update

It turns out this is a known issue - [SI-4440](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4440). The Scala compiler drops outer references for final inner classes, if they're not used (which is vaguely legitimate, as there's no possibility of subclasses using them either). One positive consequence of this is that outer classes can be garbage collected whilst inner classes are still in use, so the Scala devs are reluctant to reintroduce outer references for fear of introducing memory leaks.

Comment: Ah ok, so the `final` keyword is the problem here. I wouldn't have come up with that conclusion. In my case I only want a typesafe way to retain `A`, so an aliasing between `foo.Bar` and `bar.Bar` wouldn't actually matter, but the compiler warning is annoying enough. So I'll just drop the `final`. (I'm a bit neurotic with the `final case class`, IMO Scala should make case classes quasi-final by default, there is no reason that it doesn't).

Comment: Related discussion on scala-internals: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/vw8Kek4zlZ8/LAeakfeR3RoJ